# Can we define a new property in any of rich snippet type

Tags: html, properties, rich-snippets

Can we define a new property in any of rich snippet type.Is it possible to define new property in rich snippet type 'Product'

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the syntax you use:

1. In microdata syntax, only properties defined in the respective microdata vocabulary (e.g. schema.org) are valid. You can use external properties with their full URI if that is explicitly supported by the vocabulary. In the case of schema.org, it is currently unclear whether this holds and the Google Rich Snippet Testing Tool, http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets, throws a warning if you do.
2. In RDFa, you can use additional properties from external vocabularies, and clients should tolerate that.

For examples that work, see
    http://www.heppnetz.de/rdfa4google/testcases.html

in particular TC4,

```
http://www.heppnetz.de/rdfa4google/tc4.html
```

which works nicely with additional properties from http://purl.org/vso/ns (Vehicle Sales Ontology) in the testing tool:

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A//www.heppnetz.de/rdfa4google/tc4.html
```

Best wishes

Martin Hepp

PS: Stay tuned - there will be a new mechanism im schema.org and GoodRelations that will allow you to publish arbitrary product features with ease.